# Counting the appearances of a word in a text file in bash

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I want to count the number of appearances of each word in a file. I don't wont to count if a word exists as a sub-string inside another word. For example if the word is "**in**" I don't want to count "**in**side" as an appearance off the world.

To get the words from the text file I use:

```
#Stores the words of the file without duplicates
WORDS=`grep -o -E '\w+' $1 | sort -u -f`
```

To get all the words of the file that has been passed as command line argument.

Then I use the following command to count how many times each word appears:

```
#Accessing all the words from the file
for WORD in $WORDS
do
    #Number of apperences of the WORD in the text file ($1)
    APEARENCES=`grep -o -i "$WORD" $1 | wc -l`

    ***Code***
done
```

My problem here is that `` APEARENCES=`grep -o -i "$WORD" $1 | wc -l` `` also counts the sub-string of a word if it matches the string of the `"$WORD"`. It counts "**in**side as an appearance of the word "**in**".

EDIT: I found the solution. Turns out I just needed to add `-w` to the expression.

```
APEARENCES=`grep -o -i -w "$WORD" $1 | wc -l`
```

Comment: How is "word" defined? Replace all non-word characters by a newline, remove empty newlines, then sort -u | uniq -c. Check your script with shellcheck. Do not use backticks.

Comment: You could add the word delimiter to your grep (e.g. the space)

Comment: Sure would be easier with `awk`

Comment: Can you guys provide any examples? I am very new to bash scripting. I only started a couple days ago

Answer (score 2):

grep has `-w` to match whole words. `uniq` has `-c` to print a count.

```
grep -Eow '\w+' myfile | sort | uniq -c | sort -nk 1,1
```

Prints a sorted list of word frequencies in `myfile`.

Using `uniq -i` (not posix), case can also be ignored:

```
grep -Eow '\w+' | sort -f | uniq -ic | sort -nk 1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundary (`\\b`):

$ cat text.txt

"inside as an appearance of the word "in"

$ grep in text.txt

"**in**side as an appearance of the word "**in**"

$ grep \\bin\\b text.txt

"inside as an appearance of the word "**in**"